# Start Athena query execution fails in AWS CLI but successed in AWS management console

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have been trying to execute this sql query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appReporting.reports (
  `instanceid` string,
  `userid` string,
  `hasheduserid` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  "escapeChar" = "\\",
  "quoteChar" = '"'
)
LOCATION 's3://bucket-reporting/history/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

I can create it inside AWS console directly, but by AWS CLI command, I get all sort or errors like:

- No closing quotation ( because of `"quoteChar" = '"'` )
- EXTERNAL word is not acceppted
- backquoted identifiers are not supported
- mismatched input 'ROW' expecting {, 'WITH'}
- extraneous input 'SERDEPROPERTIES' expecting '('

Please help with this. It drives me crazy because It works fine in the console.

This is the command I make ( AWS CLI in Ansible playbook )

```
- name: Start Query Execution
  sudo: yes
  command: >
    aws athena start-query-execution 
    --query-string "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/create_table_1.sql') }}"
```

After deleting all the unwanted characters, I had: `Only external table creation is supported`

How to correctly pass the query as a string to the command?
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Any reason not to use Parquet?

Comment: what is parquet

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parquet.html

Comment: I don't understand, but that's not what i'm looking for, thanks

Comment: Parquet is a file type that you can use instead of CSVs. It will save you from quoting problems.